# Is file creation process safe among different processes at os level (ubuntu)?

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, multiprocessing

I have two java application which works on some file exist check mechanism , where one application wait till file deletion occurs and create a file on deletion of file to manage concurrency. If the process are not process safe my application fails.

Comment: Yes, file systems are thread safe, at least any of the ones that you'd want to use. But if you're trying to do IPC with flat files, I'd really suggest a better approach. This isn't the 90's anymore.

Comment: Think about what your asking. 2 applications will be running on 2 different JVM so how can the threads interfere with each other? If your threads modify the same file then there will be resource contention. This happened to any applications and not just Java.

Comment: What you mean is *process*-safe, not thread-safe. You should use a `FileLock` on a permanent file for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudocode:

```
if file exists:
   do something with it
```

It's not concurrent safe as nothing ensures the file does not get deleted between the first and the second line.

The safest way would be to use a `FileLock`. If you are planning to react to file creation/deletion events on Linux, I'd recommend to use some [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) based solution.